# How to middle align in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, alignment

Let's say I want the screen output to look like this.

```
Ship to                            Bill to
John Smith                         John Smith
222 Address                        555 Address
Los Angeles, CA                    New York, CA
```

Without hard-coding the spaces, cause once the length of the entries in the first column changes, the second column won't be aligned anymore.

Comment: use printf, and specify string with like `%20s`.

Comment: That only aligns the entire row. I want to keep both columns aligned separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example using printf:

```
#!/bin/bash

st_name="John Smith"
bt_name=$st_name
st_addr="222 Address"
bt_addr="555 Address"
printf "%-20s%s\n" "Ship to" "Bill to"
printf "%-20s%s\n" "$st_name" "$bt_name"
printf "%-20s%s\n" "$st_addr" "$bt_addr"
```

Comment: Oh! Didn't realize you could put two strings into printf. Thanks a lot